# Why I am getting error when using Dispose() in C#

Tags: c#, dispose

I am trying to dispose of the object in `c#`. But when I use the `Dispose()` method I am getting an error. I have mentioned my tried code below.

Tried code:

```
public class ParentModel : ParentModelBase, IDisposable
  {

     protected override void OnDispose()
        {
            createdObject.PageMaximizedViewModel = null;
            createdObject = null;
            createdObject.Dispose();
            base.OnDispose();
        }
  }
```

Error:

> ‘ParentCreatedClass’ does not contain a definition for ‘Dispose’ and no accessible extension method ’Dispose’ accepting a first argument of type ‘ParentCreatedClass’ could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> Can not resolve symbol ‘Dispose’

I am struggling with these hours. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The ParentCreatedClass type apparently does not implicitly implement IDisposable or otherwise have such a method called Dispose.

Comment: Also, assuming `createdObject` is `ParentCreatedClass`, in your `OnDispose` method you are setting `createdObject  = null` prior to calling `createdObject.Dispose()`.  So even if you fix the above-mentioned compile-time error, you will need to address this potential _runtime_ issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ParentCreatedClass` simply doesn't have a public `Dispose()` method - you can't call a method that don't exist....

Apparently, the `ParentCreatedClass` either doesn't implement the `IDisposable` interface, or it implements it explicitly, which means you must first cast it to `IDisposable` before you can call `Dispose()` on it - so try this:

```
protected override void OnDispose()
{
    createdObject.PageMaximizedViewModel = null;
    ((IDisposable)createdObject).Dispose(); 
    base.OnDispose();
}
```

[Here's an online demo.](https://rextester.com/RIPORG91943)

Also, Even if this code would have compiled, you're calling `.Dispose()` (or any other method for that matter) after assigning `null` to the reference will cause a `NullReferenceException` - remove the `createdObject = null;` line from your code. It's useless.

Comment: Now I am getting this error. `This type has one instance that has been disposed but is still not GCed. Investigate the instance below for more information.` How can I overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

`ParentCreatedClass` should implement IDisposable so that you are able to call `createdObject.Dispose();`

See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose) on how to implement it properly.

Similarly `ParentModel` class should implement `IDisposable` properly as described in the link.

`ParentModel` should have a `public void Dispose(){..}` method as defined in the `IDisposable` interface.